# Printing multiples of a number starting from 0 using recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, conditional-statements

Trying to find the num_multiples of `n`, starting from zero, and using recursion.

Correct Example:
Input: `print_first_multiples(5, 10)`
Output: `0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45`

I'm able to print out the spacing correctly, but I'm unable to properly increment by `n` or start from `0`.

My code below results in this:
Input: `print_first_multiples(5, 10)`
Output: `5 10 20 40 80 160 320 640 1280 2560`

I know that my recursive call for `n` is wrong, but I'm at a complete loss as to what to do. If you're able to provide help without outright solving it for me, that would be greatly appreciated!

```py
def print_first_multiples(n, num_multiples):
'''Prints out the integer multiples of n, starting with 0'''
    if num_multiples <= 0:
        print(end = " ")
    else:
        print(n, end = " ")
        print_first_multiples(n+n, num_multiples-1)
```

Comment: printing 0 as a factor for all numbers seems off

Answer (score 0):

> I know my recursive call for n is wrong, but I'm at a complete loss as to what to do. If you're able to provide help without outright solving it for me, that would be greatly appreciated!

Your recursion needs an extra parameter to be able to figure out which multiple of n is going to be printed.
I would use the following method declaration: `print_first_multiples(n, num_multiples, cur_multiple=0)`.